# Should typed factory facility throw an exception when I request a component by name which is not registered?

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

If I register a component with the container with a name (don't worry... contrived example!)

```
container.Register(Component.For<double>().Instance(Math.PI).Named("pi")
```

And ask to resolve that service type with a different name

```
container.Resolve<double>("e")
```

I get an `ComponentNotFound` exception. But now if I use the typed factory facility

```
interface IDoubleFactory { double GetDoubleByName(string name); }

container.Register(  
  Component.For<DoubleSelector, ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>()   
  Component.For<IDoubleFactory>().AsFactory(f => f.SelectedWith<DoubleSelector>())
  Component.For<double>().Instance(Math.PI).Named("pi"))

public class DoubleSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
  protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments) 
  {
    return arguments[0] as string;
  }
}
```

and try to use the factory to resolve a bogus name

container.Resolve().GetDoubleByName("e")

**I get pi back** instead of an exception. It appears that having given a name to the `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` which did not help, it has fallen back to just using the `Type` (in this case `double`) and grabbed the first thing registered against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may be a bug in Windsor 2.5.1. The contract for `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` suggests that if you return null for `ComponentType` but non-null for `ComponentName`, the lookup will be done by name, and not type. But two problems get in your way if you try to do that.

According to GitHub sources, code in `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector.BuildFactoryComponent` calls `GetCompatibleArrayItemType` on what may be a null ComponentType pointer, which causes an exception. This seems like a bug, plain and simple.

If you find a way to monkey patch that, then it appears that `TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve` method doesn't quite arrange to call the right overloads on the kernel to resolve in cases where ComponentType is null. I'm much less clear whether this is a bug or a lack in my understanding of which `IWindsorContainer.Resolve` methods do what. That said, a dispatch to the various methods (`Resolve<object>(string key)`, for example) seems to do the trick.

Both classes are unsealed, so it's straightforward to fix with derived classes.

Comment: yeah it does seem like not the best behaviour. Please log a ticket in Windsor's issue tracker.